# Printer prints pics in black and white only

Tags: windows-7, windows

My HP 4280 printer prints my saved pics in black and white but if I email the pic and attach it to the email then print it it comes out in color. What's happening?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

In windows folder right-click on image, press Print.
new window appears, options link in bottom-right corner, press it.
Press "Printer properties", on the right there should be "Color options". Pick Color and press OK, then Print

Comment: Additionally to this answer, you could go to `Control Panel` > `Printers` and right click your printer and select `printer preferences`. It may be set wrong there too. Note that outlook stores its own printer preferences and doesn't use the ones specified in the control panel once changed.

Comment: @LPChip or Chrome, maybe other browsers too